# Error when I try to download maven archtypes (mvn archtype:generate)

Tags: maven-3

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archtype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Varun.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

If I try to access http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 from the browser, I get the error:

> Browsing for this directory has been disabled. View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says "... prefix 'archtype' "
Did you try archetype rather than archtype ? :-)

Comment: Running the command prompt as administrator did the trick. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to generate archetype, then it's a typo.. It should be `archetype` instead of 'archtype`.

```
mvn archetype:generate
```